# [Joomla 3+]How to show K2 Category, to a user assigned to it

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have this problem or situation that I want to show K2 category/categories only to a user who is assigned to the specific category, if a user is logged in.
Right now it will display all the categories even if the user is logged in or not, and can add items/articles to a specific category assigned to it if he/she's logged in which works as expected.
Does anyone here knows how to solve it? Or any suggestions how can I make it work?
Any help will be much appreciated.
Joomla 3.3.6 
K2 v2.6.7

Comment: where do you maintain which user can access which k2 categories?

Comment: I assign a user to specific K2 user group and in K2 user group I assign a specific category, so if a user is logged in he/she can only access to this category and add/edit articles but only shows the categories assign to this user.

Answer (score 0):

If you can code then create a plugin in which

1. maintain mapping of k2 usergroup with allowed k2 categories
2. catch onAfterRoute trigger and add your code to check the k2 usergroup of user and its allowed k2 category.

   ```
   function onAfterRoute()
   {
     $user = JFactory::getUser();
     $groups = $user->groups;

     $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
     $option = $jinput->get('option', '');
     $view   = $jinput->get('view', '');
     $task   = $jinput->get('task', '');

     // place k2-USER-GROUP related checking here
   }
   ```

I am not sure about the view, task and other variables which k2 adds in the url while displaying category in front-end so you need to check this first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any alternative solution to this aside from coding/writing new plugin for this?

Comment: @nhinzky - A plugin is the best approach. Without it, you will have to edit core files meaning updating the K2 component will be hard and you will have to re-apply your edits and test again. And not updating should **not** be an option.

Comment: @Lodder - Thanks for that. I'm not really into coding and if you have any solutions can you help me with this?

Comment: I don't have an exact solution as I always stay well away from K2. There *might* be a 3rd party plugin that has already been developed for this. Have a look around on Google and JED.

Comment: @nhinzky - there are some extension with works on k2 restriction but their purpose is not limited to k2 completely. You can check further details at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/payplan-extensions/18603  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/16566